# Reverse FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS with PHP

Tags: php, filter

This is simple question but I am a newbie so please forgive my simple question.

Is there an easy way to reverse the effects of the FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS filter? If not how would you reverse it. Please don't just say regular expressions, actually suggest how. To be clear I am not looking to reverse the string.

Here is some sample code to help explain what I want to do:

```
/*** a string with tags ***/
$string = "<li><script>!@#$%^&*\n\'#foo</script><br><p /><li />";

/*** sanitize the string ***/
$x = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
echo $x . "<br>\n";

/*** I want this to output <li><script>!@#$%^&*\n\'#foo</script><br><p /><li /> ***/
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($x);
/*** instead it outputs: &#60;li&#62;&#60;script&#62;!@#$%^&#38;*&#10;\&#39;#foo&#60;/script&#62;&#60;br&#62;&#60;p /&#62;&#60;li /&#62; ***/
```

All ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)?  This would get you at least most of the way, and possibly be enough depending on what data was escaped.

Comment: @jedwards that did not do anything. Do you simply use it as  htmlspecialchars_decode($myString)?

Comment: `$out = htmlspecialchars_decode($in); echo $out;` -- something like that.  What does the filtered text look like?

Comment: Also consider [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: @jedwards genius answer can't believe I could not find that with all my Google searches. If you put that as answer an I will mark it as solved. Many thanks my friend. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), a more comprehensive version of `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.