# html_entity_decode after filter_var not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, encoding

I guess I'm having a problem with `html_entity_decode`, that probably has a simple solution which I've not found yet. This is my problem, I have this string:

```
L'evento dell'anno
```

Which when I save into my db, gets filtered with `filter_var($input,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` and outputs this:

```
L&#39;evento dell&#39;anno
```

Now, when I retrieve it directly from PHP inside a page, I don't need no encoding / decoding functions, and text shows as expected, as I wrote it initially, but, when I load it from AngularJS ( version 1) `$http.get()` it doesn't replace chars, if I print the object values I see all those HTML entities ( I think they are, I'm not sure ).

This is my AngularJS code part:

```
$http.get(php_data.ajax_url, {
    params: {
        action: 'get-sostenitore',
        get_id: show_id
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    // Handle data
});
```

The `// Handle data` part only prints results, nothing more.

Didn't work, so I added this PHP part:

```
$decoded_vars = array_map(function ($val) {
    return html_entity_decode($val, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
}, get_object_vars($object));
```

Doesn't work too.
I've tried `htmlentities_decode` too, `mb_convert_encoding($val,'UTF-8','HTML-ENTITIES')`, but converts special letters too ( à, è, etc... ).

I've been searching here on StackOverflow for about 2 hours, and I've found some results, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670790/reverse-filter-sanitize-special-chars-with-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638611/html-entity-decode-problem-in-php), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) (I've found another full guide to encoding / decoding here on SA, but I didn't find it again ), but none of them solved my problem.
The funny thing is that I've tried pasting my string on this [online tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities) and it shows correctly.
Could it be an AngularJS problem? I'm becoming mad for this, but I'm sure it has a really simple solution

### Update

Even if I've solved my problem, I thought it was a PHP - related issue, not JS, but I was actually wrong, so I will update the `AngularJS` part by showing how I was using the data I get:

**JS Code**

```
app.controller('eventController', ['$http', '$scope', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', '$interval', 'ngDialog', function ($http, $scope, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, $interval, ngDialog) {
    var event = this;
    $http.get(php_data.ajax_url, {
        params: {
            action: 'get-event',
            get_id: show_id
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        // Handle data
        if(response.status === 200){
            var data = response.data;
            ngDialog.open({
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                data: data,
                controller: 'dialogEventi'
                controllerAs: 'evView'
            });
        }
    });

}]);

app.controller('dialogEventi', ['$http', '$scope', '$interval', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', function ($http, $scope, $interval, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    var evView = this;
    evView.loadedItem = $scope.ngDialogData;
}]);
```

**Popup code**

```
<div id="show-event" class="bpopup-popup">
    <div class="popup-head">
        <h2>Visualizza evento</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body clearfix">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="evView.loadedItem.titolo">
                <label>Titolo:</label>
                {{evView.loadedItem.titolo}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="evView.loadedItem.descrizione">
                <label>Descrizione:</label><br/>
                {{evView.loadedItem.descrizione}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="evView.loadedItem.dataora">
                <label>Data:</label>
                {{evView.loadedItem.dataora}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="evView.loadedItem.luogo">
                <label>Luogo:</label>
                {{evView.loadedItem.luogo}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="evView.loadedItem.indirizzo">
                <label>Indirizzo:</label>
                {{evView.loadedItem.indirizzo}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by not storing HTML entities in your database! `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is pretty useless for most practical applications. Don't use it. Store plain strings in your database. [Learn about prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/476) to prevent SQL syntax issues. Learn how to handle [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/476) to preserve "special" characters correctly. Perhaps read [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze I always use prepared statements, but I thought filtering values was another better practice, my mistake. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions, I'll keep them in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of searching, I've found a solution, which is `angular-sanitize`, which I've found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize). So, to solve my problem I've just added `ngSanitize` as module dependancy.

Anyway, thanks your all your answers, I've found something interesting in each one of them which I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

So angular `{{}}` or `ng-bind` only present text. You can convert html  entities quite simply in browser by creating  dom element, inserting the string as html and retrieving it as text.

```
// simple helper function
function decode_entities(str){
  return angular.element('<div>').html(str).text()
}
```

This could be used as an angular filter or as a predecessor when you receive data

```
data.forEach(function(item){
     item.description  = decode_entities(item.description);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know about `html()` function, which would work as expected and show correct results. But it doesn't work on `ng-model`

Comment: @CapitanFindus note that you never showed how you were using the html in view

Comment: yes, I've noticed it. I thought that problem was in PHP, not JS. I'll add it

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

The manual says it will do the single and double quotes.  Because it will be like  [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) but with `ENT_QUOTES`. Maybe that's what you need.

Comment: Not actually. I've stored into database after filtering them, the problem is that they doesn't show properly when I load them using Angular